# When did the Universal Inbox become StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-button

I could swear on a recent podcast I heard @spolsky refer to it as "Universal Inbox" but now I'm seeing that the correct name is "StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™."  When did this renaming take place?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838 covers the history of the wordier (and spiffier) name.

Comment: Funny how some people can't post a question on SO with complete sentences, but the name of this thing is always perfectly preserved, all the way down to the Trademark monikers.  I guess copy-paste works after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It didn't.**

Note that the Universal Inbox is *just a part* of the "StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™", because there are other tabs; but it is an important part for most of us.
<sub>(Had to include that last part, else I would get haunted by angry red spiders)</sub>

Comment: [They're coming for you](http://xkcd.com/8/).

Comment: +1 Got it now.  I confused is-a with has-a.  Thanks for clarifying.